# Alfresco content archiving?

Tags: archive, alfresco

I have requirement where i need to archive a content item after a particular period but i should be able to access archived item anytime?

Also I want to know what is alfresco's content archiving strategy out of the box & how can i use it?

Can anybody help?

Regards.

Comment: Are you after full records management with retention, dispositions etc? Or do you just want to remove write permissions after a set length of time?

Comment: I am into mix of both where after content expiry, content should be available in repository but only visible to admin kind of users as well as not available in search. Also if a new version of content is added, it should also behave same way.

Comment: I think you'll have to write a bit of code, but Alfresco should have all the building blocks you need!

Comment: Can i use effectivity aspect here to add a rule such that one content passes its effectivity, move content to a space only accessible by admin?

Comment: Maybe, or you could just remove the permissions when it passes a certain date. You might be better off asking for advice on the Alfresco Forum - the StackExchange Q&A Format isn't a good fit for your kind of query

Comment: Thanks. I have raised same on alfresco forums @ https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/technical-architecture-discussion/what-policy-driven-storage-alfresco-0#comment-130724 but still have not got any filling reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, after some googling, i can say that content archiving in alfresco depends upon stores & can be achieved using two ways:Common & Dedicated.

1. If there is no specific need to create dedicated archival store, archiving can be implemented in same contentstore(say workspace:\\spacestore...) using aspect such as effectivity aspect or any custom aspect, adding which we can tell system that content in context is eligible for archival in same store(contentstore) and using rules/actions, content can be moved or copied in another space of same contentstore and its permissions can be updated (as & when needed).
2. If there is a need to create dedicated archival store say in large repositories or compliance based systems, new content store can be added using http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Content_Store_Selector and using cm:storeSelector aspect and setting its cm:storeName property, content can be moved/copied between stores and permissions managed.

Step 1 is more of configuration & step 2 is more of customizations.

Happy archiving.

Regards.

P.S. Feel free to add any more approaches.

Comment: Or as an alternative, use alfresco records management for content disposition which take cares of archiving more decently & provides a way to avoid customizations.

Comment: But RM use the same contentStore, in my opinion is better the first option.